# CLR Function Permissions Drop About Once A Month

Tags: sql-server-2005, sqlclr, database-permissions

Approximately once a month the production server is dropping permissions on the CLR functions. I have noticed in the logs the permissions drop coincides with the following log entry...

`07/10/2013 23:34:27,spid402,Unknown,AppDomain 2 (Database.dbo[runtime].1) is marked for unload due to common language runtime (CLR) or security data definition language (DDL) operations.`

My guess is that the CLR functions are being recompiled at that time and thus losing their permissions. If that is the correct guess, then the question is what are the possible reasons why they are being recompiled? If not, what else could be causing the permissions to drop?

**MS SQL Server 2005 (64 bit)**
**82 GB Memory**
**CLR Functions Deployed from VS 2010**

Thanks for any insight.